# Computing $ \lim_{x\to 0}\bigl(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2-x}\bigr)$

Tags: limits

Concerning the calculation of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2-x}\right)\ldots$

The answer is $-1$, but I'm not sure how this answer is correct. Please explain if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Put the two fractions to a common denominator:

$$\frac1x+ \frac{1}{x^2-1} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

What are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? Can you calculate the limit now?

Comment: Yes I can! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Common denominator:

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2 - x} = \frac{x - 1 + 1}{x^2 - x} = \frac{x}{x^2 - x}$$

Now you can simplify by $x$ and try the limit for $x\to 0$ and find out that is

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x - 1} = \frac{1}{-1} = -1$$

as wanted.